# InputMismatchException: String not recognized

Tags: java, if-statement, inputmismatchexception

I wrote the piece of Java code below. When running it and typing in any value (either one defined, e.g. latte, or any other, e.g. az integer), I get an InputMismatchException.

As far as I could find answers, this exception means that the input type does not match the expected type. What am I missing, why isn't the code recognizing a String input? Thanks for the supprort.

Cheers, Gabor

```
package Lesson1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coffee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //I define the type of coffees as Strings, plus the order as String as well
        String espresso = "espresso";
        String americano = "americano";
        String cappuccino = "cappuccino";
        String latte = "latte";
        String order = new String();

        //I ask the user for their input
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What kind of coffee would you like? We have: espresso, americano, cappuccino and latte");

        //depending on the user's choice, the corresponding name is displayed; if any other string is entered, the else clause is displayed
        if (order.equals(choice.next(espresso))) {
            System.out.println("Your order: " + espresso);

        } else if (order.equals(choice.next(americano))) {
            System.out.println("Your order: " + americano);

        } else if (order.equals(choice.next(cappuccino))) {
            System.out.println("Your order: " + cappuccino);

        } else if (order.equals(choice.next(latte))) {
            System.out.println("Your order: " + latte);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately we can't serve you. Have a nice day!");
        }

    }

}



Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at Lesson1.Coffee.main(Coffee.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the Scanner wrong. Trying using the next() method with no parameters to get the user input, and only call it once (instead of inside each if else branch). Like this:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coffee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //I define the type of coffees as Strings, plus the order as String as well
        String espresso = "espresso";
        String americano = "americano";
        String cappuccino = "cappuccino";
        String latte = "latte";

        //I ask the user for their input
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What kind of coffee would you like? We have: espresso, americano, cappuccino and latte");

        //depending on the user's choice, the corresponding name is displayed; if any other string is entered, the else clause is displayed

        String order = choice.next();
        if (order.equals(espresso)) {
            System.out.println("Your order: " + espresso);

        } else if (order.equals(americano)) {
            System.out.println("Your order: " + americano);

        } else if (order.equals(cappuccino)) {
            System.out.println("Your order: " + cappuccino);

        } else if (order.equals(latte)) {
            System.out.println("Your order: " + latte);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately we can't serve you. Have a nice day!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You write once in default input, but you're trying to read multiple times using choice.next(..).

One solution is assign your choice in a String before the if-else statement and then check it using equalsIgnoreCase.

```
    //I ask the user for their input
    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What kind of coffee would you like? We have: espresso, americano, cappuccino and latte");

    String picked = choice.next();
    //depending on the user's choice, the corresponding name is displayed; if any other string is entered, the else clause is displayed
    if (picked.equalsIgnoreCase(espresso)) {
        System.out.println("Your order: " + espresso);

    } else if (picked.equalsIgnoreCase(americano)) {
        System.out.println("Your order: " + americano);

    } else if (picked.equalsIgnoreCase(cappuccino)) {
        System.out.println("Your order: " + cappuccino);

    } else if (picked.equalsIgnoreCase(latte)) {
        System.out.println("Your order: " + latte);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Unfortunately we can't serve you. Have a nice day!");
    }
```